# How to add GPS signal strength bar in android?

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to create a GPS signal strength bar that will gauge the accuracy of the positions (the criteria would probably be 3 lowest and 10 highest ). I would like to see it like the signal bars we have on the phones telling us how our service is. Does anyone know how to create this bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem consists of two sub-problems:

### 1) How to obtain the GPS signal strength?

Looking at the [Location object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.htmlhttp://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) that is provided when your application has registered itself as a LocationListener, the object provides a `getAccuracy()` method which returns how certain the location is.

### 2) How to show a strength bar?

I assume that you want to show it in the upper notification bar. As far as I know, you won't get the bar into the right part of the bar as it's system-reserved. However, you can simply create a simple [Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) which shows the icon in the left part of your status bar. When the strength changes, just update the Icon of your notification and you're done.